# Why does Condvar thread never wake up?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

This code runs to completion and prints out the values of `my_data` if I uncomment the `sleep` line in the `do_work` function.  If I leave it commented out, my executable hangs every time.

[Why does a Condvar not wake the last thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464131/why-does-a-condvar-not-wake-the-last-thread) mentions collecting the handles and waiting for them to join in the main thread, but that should be taken care of by the rayon scope, correct?

How can I have this code complete without the `sleep` statement in `do_work()`?

```
use std::{
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
        Arc, Barrier, Condvar, Mutex,
    },
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

fn do_work(
    mtx: Arc<Mutex<bool>>,
    cond_var: Arc<Condvar>,
    barrier: Arc<Barrier>,
    quitting: &AtomicBool,
    range: &mut [f32],
) {
    while !quitting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
        barrier.wait();
        //thread::sleep(Duration::from_micros(1));
        let mut started = mtx.lock().unwrap();
        while !*started && !quitting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            started = cond_var.wait(started).unwrap();
        }
        if quitting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            break;
        } else {
            range.iter_mut().for_each(|i| *i += 1.0);
        }
    }
    println!("{:?} Joining", thread::current().id());
}

fn start_work(mtx: Arc<Mutex<bool>>, cond_var: Arc<Condvar>) {
    let mut started = mtx.lock().unwrap();
    *started = true;
    cond_var.notify_all();
}

fn reset_work(mtx: Arc<Mutex<bool>>) {
    let mut started = mtx.lock().unwrap();
    *started = false;
}
fn main() {
    let num_threads = 4;
    let test_barrier = Arc::new(Barrier::new(num_threads + 1));

    let test_mutex = Arc::new(Mutex::new(false));
    let test_cond_var = Arc::new(Condvar::new());

    let mut my_data = vec![0.0; 1024];
    my_data
        .iter_mut()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(i, iter)| *iter = i as f32);
    let chunk_size = my_data.len() / num_threads;
    let quitting = AtomicBool::new(false);
    rayon::scope(|s| {
        for chunk in my_data.chunks_mut(chunk_size) {
            let thread_mtx = test_mutex.clone();
            let thread_cond_var = test_cond_var.clone();
            let thread_barrier = Arc::clone(&test_barrier);
            let temp = &quitting;
            s.spawn(move |_| do_work(thread_mtx, thread_cond_var, thread_barrier, &temp, chunk));
        }
        test_barrier.wait();
        let _upper_bound = 1024 / num_threads;
        for _i in 0..10 {
            start_work(test_mutex.clone(), test_cond_var.clone());
            test_barrier.wait();
            reset_work(test_mutex.clone());
        }
        quitting.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
    });
    println!("my_data is: {:?}", my_data);
}
```

Cargo.toml dependencies:

```
rayon = "*"
```

This is a test for more complicated math that `do_work` will do later on, but I am trying to just get a series of threads that successfully modify a piece of a larger `Vec`.

Comment: *modify a piece of a larger Vec* — there's frequently easier ways to do that with Rayon, like using [`ParallelSliceMut::par_chunks_mut`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/slice/trait.ParallelSliceMut.html#method.par_chunks_mut). See also [How do I pass disjoint slices from a vector to different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33818141/155423); [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423).

Comment: I tried that first.  Unfortunately the latency in spinning everything up was too much.  I implemented things this way so that the threads are already spun up and ready to number crunch whenever the condition variable wakes up.

Comment: *the latency in spinning everything up was too much* — It's unrelated to this question, but that seems pretty questionable. I'd want to see benchmarks before I fully believed it.

Comment: I did benchmark it, there was a measurable difference between the condition variable waking up and par_chunks_mut.  Which is what moved me to keep my threads alive and ready for data the entire time.  I am also attempting to avoid a spinlock, which would be much simpler, but needlessly tie resources down when the threads could be sleeping.  Thank you for providing the other references, I had read those which is what lead me to the scope layout and the chunks_mut.  I didn't reference those as they seem to be working and aren't in question at the moment.

Comment: Unrelated: none of your `Arc`s are needed. Since you are using Rayon, you may pass in references (as you already read in "How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?")

Comment: I think your race condition is that one or more threads starts waiting for the barrier and then the main thread sets the `quitting` variable. Nothing will get the thread out of the `barrier.wait()` call. You can add many prints to the program. When I did so, I see the final output of one thread is `[ThreadId(8)] barrier waiting...`

Comment: And running the non-sleep code does occasionally succeed — it's all up to the whims of the OS scheduler.

Comment: Yes, what I am wondering is how to deterministically solve the problem. Adding a sleep is only a probable solution. But it seems like there should be a way with this architecture to make things work without sleep statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the intended behavior working as desired.  This seems especially convoluted and like there should be a better way. I would happily accept an answer that is less convoluted than what I have, but it at least produces the desired behavior, a threadpool with prespun threads that produce work in bursts whenever it receives the proper signal from the master thread and can shutdown in a deterministic way.  The extra starting and finishing threads provide a handshaking mechanism to ensure there are no race conditions coming up to the barriers.

```
use std::{
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
        Barrier,
    },
    thread,
};

fn do_work(
    start_barrier: &Barrier,
    finish_barrier: &Barrier,
    quitting: &AtomicBool,
    starting: &AtomicBool,
    finishing: &AtomicBool,
    range: &mut [f32],
) {
    while !quitting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
        start_barrier.wait();
        while !starting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) && !quitting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {}
        {
            // let mut started = mtx.lock().unwrap();
            // while !*started && !quitting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            //     started = cond_var.wait(started).unwrap();
            // }
        }
        if quitting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            break;
        } else {
            range.iter_mut().for_each(|i| *i += 1.0);
        }
        finish_barrier.wait();
        while !finishing.load(Ordering::SeqCst) && !quitting.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {}
    }
    println!("{:?} Joining", thread::current().id());
}

fn main() {
    let num_threads = 4;
    let start_barrier = Barrier::new(num_threads + 1);
    let finish_barrier = Barrier::new(num_threads + 1);
    let mut my_data = vec![0.0; 1024];
    my_data
        .iter_mut()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(i, iter)| *iter = i as f32);
    let chunk_size = my_data.len() / num_threads;
    let quitting = AtomicBool::new(false);
    let starting = AtomicBool::new(false);
    let finishing = AtomicBool::new(false);


    rayon::scope(|s| {
        for chunk in my_data.chunks_mut(chunk_size) {
            let thread_start_barrier = &start_barrier;
            let thread_finish_barrier = &finish_barrier;

            let thread_quitting = &quitting;
            let thread_starting = &starting;
            let thread_finishing = &finishing;

            s.spawn(move |_| do_work(   thread_start_barrier,
                                        thread_finish_barrier,
                                        thread_quitting, 
                                        thread_starting,
                                        thread_finishing,
                                        chunk));
        }
        let num_rounds = 10;
        for i in 0..num_rounds {
            let start = std::time::Instant::now();
            start_barrier.wait();
            finishing.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);
            starting.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
            finish_barrier.wait();
            if i == num_rounds-1 {
                quitting.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
            }
            finishing.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
            starting.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);
            println!("Round {} took: {:?}", i, std::time::Instant::now() - start);
        }
    });
    println!("my_data is: {:?}", my_data);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I need both the barrier and the condition variables. The starting and finishing atomic books are necessary to prevent a race condition to the barrier/condition variable. Tomorrow I will attempt to remove either the barrier or the condition variable to confirm this.

Comment: It appears that the condition_variable is redundant with the barrier.  I will edit the above and to remove the condition_variable and mark as answer unless a better response comes along.